# Mocking Segment Analytics with Jest in TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, tdd

I'm trying to write a unit test that checks if the .track method of the Analytics is called. For some reason the test keeps failing, although calling the function via http does trigger the call. I'm not sure if I've mocked it wrong, or what the issue could be?

index.ts:

```
import { Request } from "../types"
import { getSecret } from "../src/secrets"
import Analytics from "analytics-node"

const logger = (req: Request) => {
    const analytics = new Analytics(<string>process.env.WRITE_KEY);
    return analytics.track({
        userId: req.userId
    });
}

export default logger
```

index.test.ts:

```
jest.mock('analytics-node');
import { Request } from "../types"
import logger from "./index"
import Analytics from "analytics-node"

const mockAnalytics = new Analytics(process.env.WRITE_KEY = 'test');

describe('Logger tests', () => {
    it(`Should call analytics.track`, () => {
        const request: Request = {
            userId: 23
        }
        return logger(request).then(() => {
            expect(mockAnalytics.track).toHaveBeenCalled()
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: How do you think `mockAnalytics` is related to the code under test?

Comment: I'm just saving the new Analytics into a variable. Jest automatically replaces the class methods with jest.fn() and I've checked that mockAnalytics.track does exist. It's just not called.

Comment: But that's *not* the instance that the code you're trying to test is using, so why would you expect an interaction with it? It's also not a test double at all, it's a real instance.

Comment: If I console.log it in the index.ts before the return, I do get a jest mock though.

Comment: Because you *are* using `jest.mock` to mock out the module (so it's not a real instance, sorry about that), but the instance you create in the tests is *not necessarily* the same instance created in the code under test. When you say the test fails, what happens exactly? And do you have a manual mock, is it configured so that track returns a promise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using [Automatic mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#automatic-mock) by calling `jest.mock('analytics-node')`.

> Calling jest.mock('analytics-node') returns a useful "automatic mock" you can use to spy on calls to the class constructor and all of its methods. It replaces the ES6 class with a mock constructor and replaces all of its methods with mock functions that always return `undefined`. Method calls are saved in `theAutomaticMock.mock.instances[index].methodName.mock.calls`.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
import Analytics from 'analytics-node';

export interface Request {
  userId: string | number;
}

const logger = (req: Request) => {
  const analytics = new Analytics(<string>process.env.WRITE_KEY);
  return analytics.track({
    userId: req.userId,
    anonymousId: 1,
    event: '',
  });
};

export default logger;
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import logger, { Request } from './';
import Analytics from 'analytics-node';

jest.mock('analytics-node');
const mockAnalytics = Analytics as jest.MockedClass<typeof Analytics>;

describe('Logger tests', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it(`Should call analytics.track`, () => {
    const WRITE_KEY = process.env.WRITE_KEY;
    process.env.WRITE_KEY = 'test key';
    const request: Request = {
      userId: 23,
    };
    logger(request);
    expect(mockAnalytics).toBeCalledWith('test key');
    expect(mockAnalytics.mock.instances[0].track).toHaveBeenCalled();
    process.env.WRITE_KEY = WRITE_KEY;
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/65412302/index.test.ts
  Logger tests
    ✓ Should call analytics.track (4 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.954 s
```

Comment: Thank you, any ideas on how this could be done in ES5? Our cloud functions are not using TS yet.

Answer (score 0):

By using `"@segment/analytics-next": "1.49.2"`

```
let analyticsInstance: AnalyticsBrowser | null | undefined;

export const loadAnalytics = (props?: LoadAnalyticsProps): typeof analyticsInstance => {
    if ((analyticsInstance && analyticsInstance.instance?.initialized) || !props) {
        return analyticsInstance;
    }
    const { segmentAnalyticsKey, anonymousId, userId } = props;

    if (!segmentAnalyticsKey) {
        return null;
    }

    analyticsInstance = AnalyticsBrowser.load({ writeKey: segmentAnalyticsKey });
    analyticsInstance.setAnonymousId(anonymousId);
    analyticsInstance.identify(userId);

    return analyticsInstance;
};
```

mock

```
const setAnonymousIdMock = jest.fn();
const identifyMock = jest.fn();

jest.mock("@segment/analytics-next", () => {
    const originalModule = jest.requireActual("@segment/analytics-next");

    return {
        __esModule: true,
        ...originalModule,
        AnalyticsBrowser: {
            load: () => {
                return {
                    setAnonymousId: setAnonymousIdMock,
                    identify: identifyMock,
                    instance: {
                        initialized: true
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    };
});
```